# Why releasing in constructor cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: objective-c, constructor, crash, automatic-ref-counting, release

I have the following class constructor

```
- (id)initForBlurringWithConstantMaskWithID:(int)maskid andSize:(CGSize)s{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // some code

    CGImageRef maskRef = [maskUI CGImage];

    //Some code where maskRef is used

    CGImageRelease(maskRef); // I won't ever use it again
}

return self;
```

}

However, when the object is released with ARC(seems to me) everything crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_i386_GPFLT) which is usually called when "wrong" address is being accessed.

If I remove the release line everything works just fine. Anyways, can anyone explain why is it happening?

My guess is that ARC is trying to remove maskRef as well, but can't find it and it causes the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to call CGImageRelase when you create (CGImageCreate), Copy or Retain an object. `[maskUI CGImage]` doesn't claim a new ownership, therefore you are not in charge of releasing it.

Solution:
drop `CGImageRelease(maskRef);`

See 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRelease

Comment: Thank you. I did that even before writing this question. I was just wondering why is it happening.